# numba fails as soon as jitted function is called

Tags: python, function, optimization, jit, numba

I'm working on a bit of code to 'smooth' a .fits image, and although it works great, it's rather slow (approx. 3 minutes per image). I am trying to optimize the code using numba, but I'm stuck trying to get it to work with the functions I am calling. I believe the issue has to do with the way numba passes variables from one block to another.

The function 'smoother' takes a .fits file from the specified folder and feeds it (as an array) into the 'pixcal' function. 'pixcal' turns the image into a stack (i.e. a 1024x32x32 array) and then 'pixcal' feeds this into the 'boxcar' function. 'boxcar' iterates through the image and feeds the stack into 'robust_mean' which does the actual smoothing, and then the smoothed array is returned to the beginning. Here's the pastebin: https://pastebin.com/CwDbN5D3

The code fails as soon as any of the jitted functions are called, before even a single line is executed. Does anyone have a clue what's going wrong here?

Here's an error message:

```
Analyzing file 1 of 5: image_contracted_R01_M01_N02.fits
begin pixcals and smoothing (may take a while)
size of image:  (1024, 1024)
made stack:  (1024, 32, 32)
boxcar smoothing
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-29-93e136cc4875>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users', wdir='C:/Users')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Documents/AAA_Lab_Work/Python/smoothing/good_code/combined code.py", line 197, in <module>
    smoother()

  File "C:/Users/Documents/AAA_Lab_Work/Python/smoothing/good_code/combined code.py", line 186, in smoother
    hdu = fits.PrimaryHDU(pixcal(fits.getdata(filename), width, channels)) #create hdu object to encapsulate data

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py", line 307, in _compile_for_args
    return self.compile(tuple(argtypes))

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py", line 579, in compile
    cres = self._compiler.compile(args, return_type)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py", line 80, in compile
    flags=flags, locals=self.locals)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 766, in compile_extra
    return pipeline.compile_extra(func)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 362, in compile_extra
    return self._compile_bytecode()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 725, in _compile_bytecode
    return self._compile_core()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 712, in _compile_core
    res = pm.run(self.status)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 248, in run
    raise patched_exception

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 240, in run
    stage()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 433, in stage_objectmode_frontend
    cres = self.frontend_looplift()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py", line 413, in frontend_looplift
    flags=loop_flags)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\transforms.py", line 193, in loop_lifting
    cfg = compute_cfg_from_blocks(blocks)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\analysis.py", line 213, in compute_cfg_from_blocks
    cfg.add_edge(k, target)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\controlflow.py", line 83, in add_edge
    assert dest in self._nodes

AssertionError: Failed at object (object mode frontend)
```

Thanks a lot for the help :^)

Comment: Try to make this a smaller, run-able example, you're unlikely to get much help as is.  In general `numba` works best for targeted speedups (jitting smaller pieces of hot code that it can understand) rather than applying it everywhere like you're attempting.

Comment: A a first try, remove the `print` statements in the jitted functions, numba does not handle this well yet.